# Converting dataframe to array including on certain columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am looking to create an array that contains only some of the columns in a dataframe I have. Below is what Ive come up with so far however is is not in the format i want, being a numpy array.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'./data_2009.csv') 
target = df[['loan_default']]
```

Additionally, I wish for the size to be (500, ) but I am getting a shape of (500, 1). Does anyone know hoe to do this?

Comment: are you trying to Convert Selected Columns in Pandas Dataframe to Numpy Array ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the dataframe that only includes the columns you want you can call `.to_numpy()`. In your case it would be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'./data_2009.csv') 
target = df[['loan_default']].to_numpy()
```

To ensure the shape is (500,) you can call:
`target.reshape(500)`